# Extract data from coordinates

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

I need to extract data from the polygon that is located in the coordinates (lat-long).

I am using QGIS 3.16 for creating projects and QGIS Server for requesting info. I need to extract data included in the layers that are located in a specific coordinates.

For example:

[image]

The pink layer is the shapefile and the layer with numbers is WMS.

And I want to know the info for these layers (WMS and shapefile) in the coordinates of the yellow point.

Is there a solution?

UPDATE #1:
The idea is getting the layers' info from an API with an HTTP Request.

[image]

With QGIS requests like `...?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&...` it can be possible to obtain this information?

Comment: Please define "data extraction" in your context. Please add more details on the workflow you aim at.

Comment: Hi @Erik, "Data extraction" is getting all the properties that have the layers in the coordinates. The workflow consists in giving the coordinates (yellow point) as input and obtain all the layers' info as output in the response.

Comment: Then you can use the info/identify-tool.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide clarifications. Comments are for *asking* for clarifications.